# Trigger specific build pipeline in Azure Dev Ops with single repository(.sln) having multiple projects(.csproj)

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, repository, csproj, solution

I've a single repository having visual studio solution(.sln), where I've more than one project(.csproj) in same solution(i.e. WebAPI project, WebApp project etc.)...

Now, I've created separate pipeline(s) for individual project, which trigger whenever any commit comes to my XYZ branch...(ex. through PR code merge from feature to XYZ branch)

Now, the issue is...
Whenever any commit come to any project in that repository all pipeline start building there respective projects... Here I just want to build a specific project pipeline for which the commit file(s) comes into...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CeceDong-MSFT. Yes it was, and so I marked it with 'as useful' status.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify file paths to include or exclude.

```
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

When you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on. You can't trigger a pipeline with only a path filter; you must also have a branch filter, and the changed files that match the path filter must be from a branch that matches the branch filter.

Check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers